# CodeIgniter: Bring data from model to controller to use in same controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass data queried in my model to the controller, to do so I am using return $data.

My Controller (update):

```
public function order() {

$this->load->model('cost_m');

$shipping_cost = $this->cost_m->get_cost_user($this->input->post('city'));
$this->data['shipping_cost'] = $shipping_cost[0]['shipping_cost'];

      $order = array('user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                     'shipping cost' => $shipping cost,
                     'total_cost' => (($this->cart->total())+$shipping_cost),
                     'total_item' => $this->input->post('total_item'));
}
```

and My model

```
public function get_cost_user($city){
      $data = array();
      $this->db->like('city_name',$city);
      $data = return $this->_get()->result_array();

      return $data;
}
```

My problem is why my return value from get_cost_user() always giving me NULL?

Comment: You have a space between shipping and cost in: `$this->data->shipping cost`. That is a syntax error and is certainly part of the problem.

Comment: Aside from the obvious typo, `$this->data->shipping_cost` is not the same variable as `$shipping_cost`.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

First off you have a syntax error when trying to set the shipping cost. You have a space between "shipping" and "cost" in `$this->data->shipping cost =`. That is an error. Fix that to start with.

The real problem is that you are creating a variable: `$this->data->shipping_cost` and then trying to access it in the next line like so: `$shipping_cost`.

Your confusion comes from the fact that when a `view` is loaded in Code Igniter you can access variables set in the `$data` array using their index name. This is because Code Igniter does some magic behind the scenes that lets you do this.

Here is the proper way to set your shipping cost:

```
$shipping_cost = $this->cost_m->get_cost_user($this->input->post('city'));
$this->data['shipping_cost'] = $shipping_cost[0]['shipping_cost'];
```

Then in your view access the shipping cost like so:

```
var_dump($shipping_cost);
```

### Answer To Updated Code

You once again have a typo in `$shipping cost`. But that is not the issue. Change `$shipping cost` to `$this->data['shipping_cost']` in your array.

Comment: I got error. `Undefined variable: shipping_cost` and `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`. Btw I dont need show data to view.

Comment: @Vinsens You're going to have to post your updated code for me to have a chance of helping you further. The lines I wrote work. Please edit your question with the new code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is my final fixed

Controller

```
public function order() {

$this->load->model('cost_m');

$shipping_cost = $this->cost_m->get_cost_user($this->input->post('city'));
$shipping_cost = $shipping_cost[0]['shipping_cost'];

      $order = array('user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                     'shipping cost' => $shipping_cost,
                     'total_cost' => (($this->cart->total())+$shipping_cost),
                     'total_item' => $this->input->post('total_item'));
}
```

Model

```
public function get_cost_user($city){
      $data = array();
      $this->db->like('city_name',$city);
      $data = return $this->_get()->result_array();

      return $data;
}
```